# Cannot align th containg mat-form-field horizontally

Tags: html, css, angular

I am mostly a backend engineer and now i am wrestling with a CSS thing within Angular and i am out of ideas.What it is about, i have a table in angular with some th elelements, those elements are like this

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Some text">
<th mat-header-cell *someHeader>
  <div>
    <div class="mb-xs">some text</div>
    <cx-search-bar
      [blurOnValueChange]="false"
      (search)="search('some text', $event)"
      placeholder="">
    </cx-search-bar>
  </div>
</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  {{ element | getDefaultDescription }}
</td>
```

so 4 of them and the Some text div and the cx-search-bar are perfectly aligned horizontally

then on the last th i have

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
  <div>
    <div class="mb-xs">Some text</div>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select
        some logic here
      >
        <mat-option selected="true" [value]="''">Select</mat-option>
        <mat-option
          *ngFor="let productClass of productClasses$ | async"
          [value]="productClass.name ? productClass.name : null"
        >
          {{ productClass.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</th>
```

and as you can see on the screenshot there is still some bigger space between the Product class sign and the select mennu than the Description and the searchbox

i have tried with all kinds of

```
 margin-bottom ,margin-top, box-size
```

you name it, i simply cannnot allign the select and Product class with the Description and search box
i guess its because of the out of the box css of the mat-form-field and mat-select, but if anyone has any tip for me that would be great , thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: What's with that pink-ish circle button with the `+` in it - are you sure that that's not actually what is creating this space between the label text and the select field?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see CSS code, so I'll try my best to help you out. I am a bit new to Angular but not really new to CSS.

Here are 3 solutions you can try. If none of them work, tell me and I'll try to help you out.

1.

```css
.mat-select {
   position: relative;
}

.mat-option {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Or

```css
.mat-select {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center; 
}
```

Or

```css
.mat-option {
  transform: translateY(-50px) /* number was random, see what works for you */
}
```

Again, sorry if this did not help. Send me the CSS code if it did not help and I'll try my best to help you. Otherwise, I would appreciate a green tick :)